# Java Interfaces Traits

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Let's say that class2 extends another class1, and that class2 needs to implement a certain interface. Does class1 have to implement the same interface that class2 is supposed to implement?

Example:

```
public class Mosquito extends Insect implements FlyingThings {
}
```

1. Does Insects have to implement FlyingThings?
2. Or can the subclass "Mosquito" implement a class that the superclass "Insect" does not implement?

Logically, I would reason that, under the given example, the answer is no, because an Insect doesn't necessarily fly. However, of course, this example may just be misleading in that regard.

Anyway, I would like to thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Just a very minor point: I wouldn't use the word "traits" in this context because that word has a very specific technical meaning in the Scala language, which is an increasingly-popular language that runs on the Java platform.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your reasoning: Class1 does not need to implement an interface in order for Class2 to.

Class2, while inheriting the functionality and members of Class1, is free to add, or possibly alter via overrides, whatever functionality (via interfaces or otherwise) is appropriate.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!  
So, what if the superclass and subclass implement different interfaces? Must the subclass provide method definitions for all of the methods in both interfaces? 
If the subclass doesn't automatically implement interfaces implemented by the superclass, must you add a second "implements" clause?

Comment: No, the subclass does not have to do either of those things. You can have arbitrarily-deep inheritance chains, and all of the classes in the chain can be abstract. An abstract class is one that does not have to supply implementations for all methods. However, only non-abstract classes can actually be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ants are insects, and most of them don't fly. So it would be inappropriate for an ant to fly.

Further, consider this problem:

It is tempting to make

```
class FlyingInsect extends Insect
```

But then when you go do make a Queen Ant you have this:

```
class Ant extends Insect // ants don't fly

class QueenAnt extends Ant // wait she needs to fly though!
class QueenAnt extends FlyingInsect // oh drats, but now she isn't an ant!
```

Which makes `FlyingThing` an excellent choice for an interface.

Comment: To make this a bit more explicit: `FlyingThing` should indeed be an interface, because interfaces can be *multiply* inherited from in Java (you can implement multiple interfaces), but classes can only be *singly* inherited from (you can only *extend* one class).

Comment: @Robin Thanks for that clarification. I guess I was assuming certain knowledge for granted, but in hindsight that's not a guarantee. :-)